# Blue border color on menu mobile iphone only

Tags: css, elementor

When I open my dropdown menu on mobile, I have a blue border that appears around my menu button.

I don't have this one on android and also in the inspector on chrome.

I set all params to no border. See image below :

[image: Blue border on Menu mobile on Iphone only]

Comment: looks like an accessibility feature to know where the click is, not an border, that would explain why only on mobile.

Comment: Try adding `outline: none` to it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an `border`, it's an `outline`. To disable it, apply the following styles. You can also customize the outline, [learn more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline).

```css
.button {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">Button without outline</button>
```